# Django IndexError: list index out of range error

Tags: python, django

I am trying out this code i found online. When i tried commands like runserver, migrate and make migrations. All of them showed this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Django\OLD\ToDo_Application-master\ToDo_Application-master\todos\views.py", line 129, in check_time
    task()
  File "C:\Django\OLD\ToDo_Application-master\ToDo_Application-master\todos\views.py", line 155, in is_expired
    if splited_notification_time[1] == "minutes":
IndexError: list index out of range
```

CODE OF is_expired :

```
def is_expired():
    connection = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite3')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(
        " SELECT * FROM todos_todo where email_notification != '' AND notification_time != 'None' AND sent_reminder == 'False' ")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    todo_notify_time = 0

    for row in rows:
        todo_item_id = row[0]
        due_date_in_ms = int(datetime.fromisoformat(row[3]).timestamp() * 1000)
        current_date = int(datetime.now().timestamp() * 1000)
        splited_notification_time = str(row[6]).split(" ")
        receiver_email = row[5]
        sent_reminder = row[7]
        date_in_pst = due_date_in_ms - (7 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
        time_remaining = date_in_pst - current_date

        if splited_notification_time[0] != "None":
            if splited_notification_time[1] == "minutes":
                todo_notify_time = int(
                    (splited_notification_time[0])) * 60 * 1000
            elif splited_notification_time[1] == "hours":
                todo_notify_time = int(
                    (splited_notification_time[0])) * 60 * 60 * 1000
            elif splited_notification_time[1] == "day":
                todo_notify_time = int(
                    (splited_notification_time[0])) * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000

        if time_remaining <= todo_notify_time:
            todo_item_expire = "Your todo_item name - " + \
                str(row[1]) + " will expire in " + str(row[6]) + "! "

            send_mail(
                'Todo_Notification',
                todo_item_expire,
                'noreply@todo_application.ca',
                [receiver_email],
                fail_silently=False,
            )

            selected_todo_item = get_object_or_404(Todo, pk=int(todo_item_id))
            selected_todo_item.sent_reminder = "True"
            selected_todo_item.save()
```

---

There is one line in the code which is showing an error as well. I have pasted the code below with the error.

CODE :

```
<script>
     timer_interval("{{todo.id}}" , "{{ todo.due_date|date:"M d, Y H:i:s" }}");
</script>
```

ERROR :

```
',' expected.javascript
```

Comment: For your second error, it's because you're using double quotes within double quotes.  It should be `timer_interval("{{todo.id}}" , "{{ todo.due_date|date:'M d, Y H:i:s' }}");`.  For your first error, try `print(splited_notification_time)`.  I'm not sure what's causing it, but is it printing what you expect?  Probably only one character, which is why the index of 0 works, but not the index of 1.  The list only has one item.

Comment: The second error is resolved now.  As for the first error, it is returning ```['False']```

Answer (score 2):

Check what `splited_notification_time` is returning.

It appears that there is no `" "` in `row[6]` resulting in `splited_notification_time` being a list of length 1.

Therefore, there will be no second element (which you are trying to access), giving you the error.

Comment: It is returning ```['False']```

Comment: I missed that, I thought it would just be one character in the string, totally ignoring the `split(" ")` part.

Answer (score 0):

First, Alec Hamilton's answer is correct, and I missed it thinking you would see just one character in a string.

I'm not sure what `splited_notification_time` is supposed to return, but since it is returning `['False']` try

```py
if splited_notification_time[0] != "False":
```

Perhaps it's just me, but your query looks like [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/), as opposed to Django.

```py
connection = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite3')
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(
    " SELECT * FROM todos_todo where email_notification != '' AND notification_time != 'None' AND sent_reminder == 'False' ")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
print(rows)    # WHAT DOES THIS PRINT?
```

Try printing rows.  Is *this* what you expect?  Perhaps the issue is the query itself?  If you need to use a query like that without using the Django ORM, then you could use a [raw SQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/sql/) in Django.

Finally to make my answer complete, the answer to your second error, which you have already resolved, as I mentioned in my comment is to remove the double quotes within the double quotes in your HTML, like this:

```html
<!-- Change -->
    timer_interval("{{todo.id}}" , "{{ todo.due_date|date:"M d, Y H:i:s" }}");
<!-- to -->
    timer_interval("{{todo.id}}" , '{{ todo.due_date|date:"M d, Y H:i:s" }}');
```